# How do I use gspread-formatting (or gspread) to change background color for entire columns?

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

Apologies, I do see similar questions. But, as far as I can tell, I am using the solutions posted there (I really have done my best to make sure I'm not wasting y'all's time)!

I am doing a bunch of analysis of political districts and am generating reports using Google Sheets.

So, after creating a dataframe and doing a million calculations, I go to save it to Google Sheets (which works, I can totally save it all), but I want to color the columns for the corresponding party.

My current code looks like this, and everything works except the coloring of the columns.

````
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import colors
from gspread_formatting import *
def save_to_google_sheets(df,spreadsheet_name,worksheet_name,folder_id=None,coloring={}):
    """save dataframe worksheet"""
    # get spreadsheet and worksheet instances (open if they exist, create if they don't)
    ss,ws=get_worksheet(spreadsheet_name,worksheet_name,folder_id)
    # save dataframe to worksheet
    set_with_dataframe(ws,df,include_index=True,include_column_header=True,resize=True)
    # figure out how many rows each column will be
    num_rows=len(ws.get_values())
    # get which level of the pandas MultiIndex tells us the 'party'
    col_pty_lvl=df.columns.names.index('party') if 'party' in df.columns.names else None
    if col_pty_lvl:
        # get all parties in race
        parties=ws.row_values(col_pty_lvl+1)
        # color columns for each party included in dictionary
        pty_colors={'democratic':'blue','republican':'red'}
        for pty,clr in pty_colors.items():
            # get red, green, and blue values for given color
            # ex: r=1.0, g=0.0, b=0.0
            r,g,b,a=colors.to_rgba(clr)
            # get index of all columns belonging to this party
            pty_cols=[i for i,p in enumerate(parties) if p==pty]
            # set background color for each column
            for c in pty_cols:
                fmt=CellFormat(backgroundColor=Color(r,g,b),
                    horizontalAlignment='CENTER')
                # get A1 notation of column
                # sample output: 'B1:B93'
                a1=f'{gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(1,c)}:{gspread.utils.rowcol_to_a1(num_rows,c)}'
                format_cell_range(ws,a1,fmt)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change with [worksheet].format, maybe helpful:

```py
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
   
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("your json service account", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key("key of your spreadsheet")
ws = spreadsheet.worksheet("workssheets name")
# range, white background:
ws.format("A1:E10", { 'backgroundColor': {
    'red':1.0,
    'green':1.0,
    'blue':1.0}})
# entire columns, as RGB:
ws.format("A:E", { 'backgroundColor': {
    'red':255/255,
    'green':255/255,
    'blue':255/255}})
```